# full table scan when indexes are available

Tags: sql, mysql, database, performance

I have a number of queries with a similar collection of joins. For some reason they are all suffering from table scans on one of the joins.

```
   SELECT S.shape_id, 
          S.title, 
          G.grid_id, 
          CI.city_id, 
          CI.city_name, 
          CO.country_code, 
          CO.country, 
          U.user_id, 
          U.username, 
          GA.first_name, 
          GA.fb_id 
     FROM shape S 
     JOIN spots SP ON S.shape_id = SP.shape_id 
     JOIN grid G ON SP.grid_id = G.grid_id 
     JOIN city CI on G.city_id = CI.city_id 
     JOIN country CO ON CI.country_code = CO.country_code 
     JOIN user U on S.user_id = U.user_id 
LEFT JOIN gamer GA ON U.user_id = GA.user_id 
    WHERE S.status > 0
      AND U.user_id != 2579 
 ORDER BY S.views ASC 
    LIMIT 111, 1
```

The table scan always seems to be on the table 'grid' / 'G'.

Here is the 'EXPLAIN'

```
    ID - SELECT TYPE - TABLE - TYPE - POSS KEYS - KEY - KEY LEN - REF - ROWS - EXTRA
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1 - SIMPLE - G - ALL - PRIMARY - null - null - null - 405 - Using temporary; Using filesort    
    1 - SIMPLE - CI - eq_ref - PRIMARY - PRIMARY - 3 - ft_game.G.city_id - 1     
    1 - SIMPLE - CO - eq_ref - PRIMARY - PRIMARY - 6 - ft_game.CI.country_code - 1     
    1 - SIMPLE - SP - ref - shape_id,grid_id - grid_id - 4 - ft_game.G.grid_id - 1 - Using where    
    1 - SIMPLE - S - eq_ref - PRIMARY,user_id - PRIMARY - 4 - ft_game.SP.shape_id - 1 - Using where    
    1 - SIMPLE - U - eq_ref - PRIMARY - PRIMARY - 3 - ft_game.S.user_id - 1     
    1 - SIMPLE - GA - eq_ref - PRIMARY - PRIMARY - 3 - ft_game.S.user_id - 1
```

1. I am confused by the order of the explain... Why is G (grid) first?
2. Why is there a table scan on grid when I have a key that is G.grid_id (the primary key).
3. Why is there a temporary table created?

Comment: Thank you for neatening my table OMG Ponies :)

Comment: How many rows exist in each table?  If there are "few" rows (and the database gets to decide what "few" means) it may decide that it's faster to scan the table than to use an index.

Comment: There is about 400 rows. There is no grid.city_id index... as the queries are always grid->city->country and not the other way. I tested an index on there just incase... made no difference

Answer (score 0):

I am no mysql guru. On the other hand I think baselines for Oracle are similar. Based on them:

The main drivers behind full table scan or index scan is selectivity. The more different values are there in a column, the more likely index will be used. If database expects that more than 10 percent of the rows will be fetched, it will likely use full table scans.

I suppose gridId is unique in the grid table. So the selectivity is high. BUT you use an other column city_id. This means, that even if you would use the index to fetch the id, the table data is also needed, since the additional column is there. And if it means, that more than 10 percent of the rows will be fetched, it will not use index.

There are multiple join methods. Based on the [join method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Join_algorithms), different behaviour is present.

For [hash join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join) and [nested loops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191318.aspx) the driver table is the smaller or smallest, or the one that have the most selective predicate. So I suppose grid is your smallest table. And since your SQL does not have any equivalency based condition (you have a > and a !=) you should not wonder about that database will use the smallest table as a driver.

So the main reason for full table scan is that you do not have any selective condition and the database should start from full table scan, and it picked grid. Thats all.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that MySQL doesn't support hash joins.

Comment: Yep. I said I have competence to Oracle :D Anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

You say the table only has 400 rows. I know in SQL Server it would be unlikely to use an index in a tiny table like that. I suspect mySQL would feel the same way.

If the table is large and it is still not using an index, check to make sure that you have a good index for it to use. For instance, FKs should usually be indexed and some people think they are automatically, but they are not in all databases. You'd be surprised how often your first check shows no index for something you were sure would have been there.